# XNA sound effect

Tags: c#, xna

I have a little problem with a sound effect. It doesn't function well because when I play it is played around 500000 times in two seconds. Take a look look here:

```
SoundEffect thunder;
thunter=Content.Load<SoundEffect>("thunder");

foreach (flash flash in flashes)
   if(flash.visible==true)
       if (time >1 && time <3)
            thunder.Play(); //now it sounds bad because it is played a lot of times.. I want it to be played only once! (the sound is 5 sec long)
```

Comment: XACT has a property for the sounds to make sure it can't be played again whilst it is in use, I can't remember the exact property name but you need to activate it..

Comment: Scroll down a little bit on [this book](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=PoPw--vPXfUC&pg=PA198&lpg=PA198&dq=xact+playback+properties&source=bl&ots=9ue55Ng388&sig=tOEF1o7n_9bJfWqG5lauU5vScvo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=y0CMU9-JDoK-O6qPgcAM&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=xact%20playback%20properties&f=false) to page 202 to see cue instance limiting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm. Could it be as simple as this:

```
foreach (var flash in flashes)
   if (flash.visible && time > 1 && time < 3)
   {
        thunder.Play();
        break; // play sound only once
   }
```

Comment: It would depend on the games FPS and how long the sound is.. this would help but not an ideal solution

Comment: It doesn't function bro.. I don't know why -.-

Comment: @user3641178 - If your game is 60 frames per second then it still runs this line of code 60 times in a second.. please see the link I provided in my other comment.

Comment: Thank you very much :) now i gonna try

Comment: Anyway.. I don't find an example there.. have I to use a SoundEffectInstance?

Comment: I don't understand anyway.. I need to know how to do it in XNA with c#

Comment: If `SoundEffect` has properties/methods to know when effect is being played, then make this effect global (don't create it each time) and call them before `thunder.Play()`. Other *cheap solution* would be to count time (or executions) from the moment you start playing to decide whenever to start *new* effect or not. It's a bit unclear what you want. Do you want that thunder sounds continuously (one after another) or once per 20 seconds. Or what is the criteria?

Comment: Thanks a lot for support and being patient!!